# Can someone explain me how to read members of a set to prove uncountability?

Tags: definition, alternative-proof

I have trouble in understanding what the elements in the following set are:
$$
V = \{f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N} \mid
 \text{there is $N_f \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $f(x) \le N_f$ for all $x\in\mathbb{N}$}
\}.
$$

I always have trouble in reading these definitions in a normal way. Can someone explain me how to read definitions (or sets) like these and what the members of this set are?

I have to prove whether this set is countable or not, but for that I first have to understand what the set actually means.

Thank you.

Comment: I disagree with the vote to close.  This is definitely on topic, and is not asking for the solution to the base problem but with understanding part of it.

Comment: I don't want the answer, I can come up with that myself. I just want to understand the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to take it apart.  First, $V$ is the set of all functions from $\Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ that satisfy the given condition.  That gets us thinking about the right stuff.  What is the condition?  That the function $f$ has some $N_f$ (that depends on $f$) so that all the values of $f(x)$ are less than or equal to $N_f$.  This means (across all $x \in \Bbb N$) there is some number greater than all the $f(x)$, which is an upper bound.  This is the set of all bounded functions.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the information. I do understand it a little better now. Do you have any general tips on understanding these definitions? Most of the time I have a problem in understanding the question and not in solving it.

Comment: It takes practice.  I was trying to show a way to think about the definition, breaking it down into pieces, so you can understand each piece.  As you understand each one, it helps you see what the others are, then put the pieces together.  That is how I approach it when I don't see it immediately.

Comment: Ok, well thank you for the help, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

It's the set of bounded functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1):

Interpret from the inside out.

"$f(x)\le N_f$": The value of $f$ at $x$ is at most $N_f$.

"$f(x)\le N_f$ for all $x\in\mathbb{N}$": *Every* value of $f$ is at most $N_f$.  The graph of $f$ would lie completely below the line $y=N_f$.  In short, $f$ is bounded above by $N_f$.

"there is some $N_f\in\mathbb{N}$ so that $f(x)\le N_f$ for all $x\in\mathbb{N}$": There is *some* line $y=N_f$ below which the graph of $f$ lies.  That just means the graph of $f$ doesn't go up forever.  In short, $f$ is bounded above.  (The subscript $f$ on $N_f$ indicates that the value of $N_f$ might depend on $f$, that is, if we consider more than one $f$ at some point, different $f$s could have different $N_f$s.  Maybe that will be important later.)

"$\{f\colon\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}\;|\;\text{there is...}\}$": The set of functions $f$ mapping $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ such that $f$ is bounded above.

So, $V$ is the set of bounded functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$.

Looking back at that subscript, it seems that the author was concerned that the reader would maybe think that all the functions in $V$ were bounded by one and the same $N$, that every function's graph lay below the same line $y=N$.  By writing $N_f$, the author has emphasized that that's not what they meant.  (I think this was clear from the logical structure of what they wrote, but some mathematical communities — especially those made up of old-fashioned analysts, in my experience — prefer to write these subscripts.)

Comment: Thank you Steven, the author is indeed an old-fashioned guy :)